# sco programs on linux

Tags: kernel, patch

I have a situation where we are moving our sco based server to linux but
need 3 sco programs to run. I know there is a kernel patch that should allow
me to do that but that is where I am stuck. can anyone out there help me?

Comment: What's a "sco program"? Do you have the source? Are you trying to move a binary executable from SCO Unix to "linux"? What happens when you copy the "sco files" to Ubuntu, and do `file sco1;ldd sco1;file sco2;ldd sco2;file sco3;ldd sco3`?

Comment: SCO is real Unix. After all the legal issues, since changed name. But software related to original AT&T Unix. While many command use similar syntax, it is not Linux.

Comment: I'm faced with the same problem @CurtisSchell. Please let me (DaleEMoore@gMail.Com) know how you resolved this issue!